# How to fix this program so it searches only my name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search

I am learning ***JavaScript*** and i built this program, that *searches* for instances of the letter E within  the `String`, and than stores letter by letter to an `array` but now when it finds a similar instance of the letter E it also outputs the similar instance, in this case i have Eddie, and Eric. And i don't want it to output the similar instance which is Eric in this case. I know there is a hacky way to do it, something like `if(nameYouFound !== "myName")`. But i don't like it... On the website where i learned this, it says there is built in JavaScript, `string` method that can help. Do you know what is the method that can solve the problem?

> **Please don't answer with JQuery, i am trying to get better at
>   JavaScript...**

Here is the code snippet:

```js
/*jshint multistr:true */
var text, myName, hits, i, j;
text = "Hello, there, how are you feeling Eddie hope you are ok, ok Eric";
myName = "Eddie";
hits = [];
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] === "E") {
    for (j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
      hits.push(text[j]);
    }
  }
}

if (hits.length == 0) {
  alert("Your name was not found!")
} else {
  alert(hits);
}
```

Comment: this isn't searching for a "name" within the string, it is searching for instances of the letter `E`.

Comment: @Claies thanks ill edit it

Comment: **but now when it finds a similar name it also outputs the similar name, in this case i have Eddie, and Eric. And i don't want it to output the similar name.** I don't understand this

Comment: @jonju thanks for noticing, i edited it now

Comment: the logic in this code is "find the capital E, then write the same number of letters into the hits array as the number of letters in the string "Eddie"."  Of course this is going to find "Eric "....

Comment: @Claies ok, i understand it now, but thats what i want to solve, i dont want that "Eric" in my output, and i am looking for a String method that can solve it :) Im just a beginner ...

Comment: by the way, `if(nameYouFound !== "myName")` won't work, because you never find more than a single `E`.  and there isn't any `String` method that would work here either, again because you aren't searching for a string, you are searching for a single character.

Comment: So you want to search for your name only in the string and nothing else?

Comment: The method you are looking for is indexOf()

Comment: also of note, this output is not an array of two elements `Eddie` and `Eric `, it is an array of individual characters, `[E][d][d][i][e][E][r][i][c][ ]`.

Comment: @Claies i know, i didnt create two arrays,i stored it i one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in indexOf() method for strings.

```
var text = "Hello, there, how are you feeling Eddie hope you are ok, ok Eric";
var myName = "Eddie";
var hits = [];
var startIndex = text.indexOf(myName);
if (startIndex !== -1) { // myName exists in text
    for (var i = startIndex; i < startIndex + myName.length; ++i) {
        hits.push(text[i]);
    }
}
else {
    // Do whatever you want like.. 
    console.log("Not Found!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your title of,

> How to fix this program so it searches only my name?

and my understanding of your problem here is something that might help you:

```js
        var text = "Hello, there, how are you feeling Eddie hope you are ok, ok Eric";
 var myName = 'Eddie';

 if (text.search(myName)!== -1) {
  alert('Eddie found');
 } else {
  alert('Eddie not found');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this get you what you are looking for

```js
/*jshint multistr:true */
var text, myName, hits, i, j;
text = "Hello, there, how are you feeling Eddie hope you are ok, ok Eric";
myName = "Eddie";
var isFound=text.includes(myName);
var index= text.indexOf(myName);
if(isFound){
  alert("You name was found by using \"includes\" method");
}else{
  alert("You name was not found with \"includes\" method");
}
if(index>=0){
   alert("You name was found at "+ index +" by using \"indexOf\" method");
}else{
  alert("You name was not found with \"indexOf\" method");
}
```

Comment: it does works with version 12.0. [See](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

Comment: This is a bit redundant if you can find a valid index with indexOf() that means the word you are looking for is included and if you get -1 the word is not there